# Heroku Bonsai with gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails' still looking for port 9200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I followed Heroku's instructions on setting up Bonsai Elasticsearch:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai

with all of these in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails'
```

However when I still get the following connection error when I run:

```
heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='class' FORCE=true --trace

- - returns - - 

rake aborted!
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
```

Elasticsearch works locally, I can't get it to work on Heroku.

My model is:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Search
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

end

Property.import
```

I have a rake file:
lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
```

I am using Devise too but I don't think it is impacting this.  On Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1.2.

Any suggestions?

** edit **

I took out the bonsai-elasticsearch-rails gem and added:
config/initializers/bonsai.rb

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL']
```

Still running into the same error with it looking for port 9200

```
heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Property' FORCE=true --trace
Running `bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS=Property FORCE=true --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.8668
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke elasticsearch:import:model (first_time)
** Execute elasticsearch:import:model
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties"
2014-10-07 22:39:25 +0000: [Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 {:host=>"localhost", :port=>"9200", :protocol=>"http"}
[!!!] Error when deleting the index: Faraday::ConnectionFailed
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
2014-10-07 22:39:25 +0000: [Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 {:host=>"localhost", :port=>"9200", :protocol=>"http"}
2014-10-07 22:39:25 +0000: [Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 {:host=>"localhost", :port=>"9200", :protocol=>"http"}
[!!!] Error when creating the index: Faraday::ConnectionFailed
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
  Property Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties"   ORDER BY "properties"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
2014-10-07 22:39:25 +0000: [Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 {:host=>"localhost", :port=>"9200", :protocol=>"http"}
rake aborted!
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:104:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:81:in `bulk'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:120:in `block in import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:96:in `block in __find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:125:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/proxy.rb:80:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:95:in `__find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:119:in `import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-rails-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:104:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.5/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:81:in `bulk'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:120:in `block in import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:96:in `block in __find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:125:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/proxy.rb:80:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:95:in `__find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:119:in `import'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-rails-0.1.6/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => elasticsearch:import:model
```

** edit 2 **

Same error using:

```
elasticsearch-model 0.1.4 or 0.1.6
elasticsearch-rails 0.1.4 or 0.1.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out this line in my model was overwriting other settings:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
```

This error goes away if I set it to this:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL'], log: true
```

Thanks to Nick and Rob for helping me out.  Now on to the next error...

**update 12-29-2014
I ran into the same error running this from a new install, fixed it with typing

```
$ elasticsearch
```

in the console to start elasticsearch.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: where did you run $ elasticsearch? same issue has been driving me crazy and cant fix.

Comment: This was from the console of the server, run this on your console to get into it:    heroku run rails console

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
```

and it solved this for me.